# check data in table row is < or >

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this,

```
KOD    Voucher
1        10
2         2
3        11
4         5
5        23
6         1
7        23
```

I just want the result is like this

```
< 10 = 3
> 10 = 4
```

How to do that in sql?

Comment: As `> 10 = 4` presumably you mean `>= 10`

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN voucher < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "< 10",
  SUM(CASE WHEN voucher > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "> 10"
FROM table;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b79a/1)

But this will give you only 3 for those that `> 10`:

```
< 10  > 10
3       3
```

You have to use the predicate `>=` to get 4 values for `> 10` since 10 not `> 10` nor `< 10`.

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b79a/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS "< 10"
FROM myTable
WHERE Voucher < 10 

SELECT COUNT(1) AS ">= 10"
FROM myTable
WHERE Voucher >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In row form

```
  select case when voucher<10 then '< 10' else '>= 10' end breakdown,
         count(1) total
    from tbl
group by case when voucher<10 then '< 10' else '>= 10' end;
```

Result:

```
 breakdown | total
 < 10      | 3
 >= 10     | 4
```

In column form

```
  select count(case when voucher<10 then 1 end) [< 10],
         count(case when voucher>=10 then 1 end) [>= 10]
    from tbl;
```

Result:

```
 < 10  | >= 10
 3     | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select '< 10 = '+cast(count(KOD) as Varchar(100)) from t where Voucher<10
union
select '> 10 = '+cast(count(KOD) as Varchar(100)) from t where Voucher>=10
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9df39/8)